# Python 2.7: Error in unit-testing exception using mock library

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, mocking

I'm writing unit test for following method `_make_post_request` of `APIClient` class. But I'm having problem in writing unit test for this particular method. This method calls two more methods, out of which one raises an exception. I'm trying to `mock` both the methods and assert the exception is being raised.

I'm not able to understand how do I mock both methods *in correct order*, i.e. `requests.post` and `_raise_exception` at the same time. Also how can I *verify* that the exception was indeed raised in the test.

The case I'm testing is when response `status_code` is not `200` and hence, a `APIRequestError` exception is raised by `_raise_exception` method.

```
import requests

class APIClient:

    def _make_post_request(self, url, data=None, headers=None):
        try:
            resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
            if resp.status_code == 200:
                return resp
            else:
                self._raise_exception(resp)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            print("Connection Error")
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            ......

    @staticmethod
    def _raise_exception(resp):
        status_code = resp.status_code
        error_code = resp.headers['Error-Code']
        error_msg = resp.headers['Error']
        raise APIRequestError(status_code, error_code, error_msg)
```

Here's what I have tried so far. But this test is failing.

```
import unittest
import mock

class APITest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        api = APIClient()

    @mock.patch.object(APIClient, '_raise_exception')
    @mock.patch('APIClient.api.requests.post')
    def test_make_post_request_raise_exception(self, resp, exception):

        resp.return_value = mock.Mock(status_code=500, headers={
                                 'Error-Code': 128, 'Error':'Error'})

        e = APIRequestError(500, 128, 'Error')
        exception.side_effect = e

        req_respone = self.api._make_post_request(url='http://exmaple.com')


        exception_response = self.api._raise_exception(req_response)

        # NOW WHAT TO DO HERE?
        # self.assertRaises(??, ??)
        self.assertRaises(e, exception) # this results in error
        self.assertEqual('', exception_response) # this also results in error
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
return func(*args, **keywargs)
File ".../api/tests/test_api.py", line 82, in test_make_post_request_raise_exception
req_respone = self.api._make_post_request(url='http://example.com')
File "api/apiclient/api.py", line 52, in _make_post_request
self._raise_exception(resp)
File ".../venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1062, in __call__
return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
File ".../venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1118, in _mock_call
raise effect
APIRequestError
```

Can anyone explain me what could be the possible reason for this error? Which method call is possibly going wrong?

Comment: are you trying to mock status code as 500 and expect no exception ?

Comment: @IndraUprade No, I'm trying to mock status code 500. An exception will be raised, and that's what I expect to happen. But how do I write a test for this whole sequence, i.e. request returns 500 => `_raise_exception` called => `APIRequestError` exception raised.

Comment: try to put your test case under try catch block and catch the exception and assert it

Comment: @IndraUprade Sorry, I'm not able to follow. Are you saying I should replace `if resp.status_code == 200: return resp else:` block by a try-catch or I should introduce a try-catch *inside test* (which don't think is a good idea)? Can you give an example via answer?

Comment: No your test class